# How to set 'to email address' in PayPal's express-checkout?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

**The setup:**
I have a paypal business account with a primary email and several secondary or alternate emails.
I can configure adaptive payments to go to a specific alternate email, thus differentiating where the payment came from.

**The problem:**
Developing express-checkout payments using the "SetExpressCheckout" and "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" API calls I came across the problem that 'to email address' can not be explicitly set and all payments end up showing up as made to the primary paypal email address.

[Some suggest using the "SUBJECT" query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29451422/3319298), but it does not seem to work.

Is it possible to specify which email address an express payment should go to, and if so, how?

Here is the Ruby code that controls what query parameters are passed to "SetExpressCheckout":

```
hash = {
    "USER" => user_id,
    "PWD" => password,
    "SIGNATURE" => signature,
    "METHOD" => "SetExpressCheckout",
    "RETURNURL" => options[:return_url], # URL of your payment confirmation page
    "CANCELURL" => options[:cancel_url], # URL redirect if customer cancels payment
    "VERSION" => 124, # this may increase in the future
    "SOLUTIONTYPE" => "Sole",
    "LANDINGPAGE" => "Billing",
    "EMAIL" => options[:email],
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID" => options[:receiver_email], # explictly set what paypal account will recieve the payment
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION" => "SALE",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" => options[:receiver_amount],
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE" => options[:currency_code],
    "SUBJECT" => options[:receiver_email]
}
```

And "DoExpressCheckoutPayment:

```
hash = {
    "USER" => user_id,
    "PWD" => password,
    "SIGNATURE" => signature,
    "METHOD" => "DoExpressCheckoutPayment",
    "VERSION" => 124,
    "TOKEN" => options[:token],
    "PAYERID" => options[:PayerID],
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID" => options[:receiver_email], # explictly set what paypal account will recieve the payment
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION" => "SALE",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" => options[:receiver_amount],
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE" => options[:currency_code],
    "SUBJECT" => options[:receiver_email]
}
```

Notice that I set "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID" parameter to one of the alternative paypal account emails at every opportunity.